# How should I use push notification of android for iOS

Tags: c#, ios, .net, push-notification

I have using this code for sending notification to android device, but it's not working for iOS device

iOS developer set deviceId of apple during register and I have using it

```
public string SendNotification(string message, string deviceId, bool IsiOS)
        {

            try
            {
                string SERVER_API_KEY = "AIzaS......gcw";
                if (IsiOS)
                {

                    SERVER_API_KEY = "AIza.......3k";
                }
                var SENDER_ID = "tok.....712";
                //"850.........538";
                var value = message;
                WebRequest tRequest;
                tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");

                //"https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
                tRequest.Method = "post";
                tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";


                tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", SERVER_API_KEY));

                tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

                string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=604800&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" +
                                  System.Uri.EscapeDataString(value) + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() +
                                  "&registration_id=" + deviceId + "";
                Console.WriteLine(postData);
                Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

                Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                dataStream.Close();

                WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

                dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

                StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

                String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();


                tReader.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
                tResponse.Close();
                return sResponseFromServer;
            }
            catch
            {
                return "";
            }

        }
```

Am I must to change anything else ?

Note: I just change "Key" and deviceId"

Also the json that I send to apple device is like this:

> {     "to": "cu8FBLt..................WRFw61",    "notification": {
>         "title": "title",       "body": "des...",       "badge": 1  } }

Answer (score 0):

You did not tell us what - or if - you have configured the firebase console. Have you uploaded the APN certificate to your firebase project?

Have a look at this detailed [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/firebase-push-notifications/), especially at this chapter: 
"Configuring Firebase for Push Notifications"

It is definitively more complex to get Push Notifications running than just changing the id's.

Comment: My iOS developer said my server code is wrong, and he is done anything , also I get this error during send **Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.**

Comment: Could you try with the header "Content-Type: application/json" ?

Comment: I did, nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a certificate for push notification?
You have to add a certificate for ios.

Steps to add certificate:

- Export certificate from keychain
- Add password on the certificate when exporting.
- Use certificates with a password for push notification in c#.